# Trying to use a composite unique index instead of a composite unique identifier

Tags: sql-server, outsystems

I am evaluating outsystems and am trying to write a PoC List/CRUD app based on a legacy database table (the structure of which cannot be changed) which does not have a primary key but instead has two text fields that together constitute a unique index.  The database is SQL Server 2014.

The table is successfully added in Integration Studio using "Connect to External table or view".

Then when I open the TestApp in Service Studio and go to the data tab I see the entity there, but it's not usable because it has no identifier defined.  I have read some online info that I can double click on the entity and go to the Indexes tab.  Here I normally would expect to see the index already defined in the database but it's not there.  I also expect to the the New and Delete buttons to be enabled so I can create and delete indexes but New is disabled.

Am I correct to assume that OutSystems should have already "seen" the existing composite unique index?  If so, am I correct to assume that this index would have sufficed to create a pseudo/virtual identifier for the entity, whereby making the entity system happy for CRUD and List operations?  And also why is the New button not enabled for me to even manually create the index?

Can someone help me please in the correct direction?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The OutSystems platform only supports single primary keys, so you have to create the CRUD operations by hand.

For external entities, index information is not fetched from the database, and the reason you can't create the index is because OutSystems doesn't control the metadata (i.e. you can't create indexes, create/modify columns, etc).

Comment: Thanks! How does one create CRUD ops by hand?  And will the same smart actions to automatically create CRUD screens still be available?

Comment: You should have a Create<EntityName> action to create even without a primary key, unless the database connection is strictly read-only. What you won't have are the other entity actions that require and Id (delete, update, createorupdate). For those you can use a SQL (aka Advanced) node with the appropriate SQL statement.